# Conditional probability vs intersection.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are 5 machines in a factory, out of which 3 are working correctly. They produce 10% of the defective items independently. Remaining 2 machines have 20% defective item production.

A machine is chosen at random and five articles produced by the machine are examined. What is the probability that the machine chosen is defective given that of the 5 articles examined 2 are imperfect and 3 are perfect.

---

In the solution, at the beginning they have calculated

$P(D\mid M) = {^5C_2} \cdot (0.1)^2\cdot (0.9)^3$.

Here $D$ stands for picking 3 perfect and 2 imperfect articles and $M$ stands for machine working correctly.

Here I don't understand why

$P(D \cap M) = {^5C_2} \cdot (0.1)^2\cdot (0.9)^3$. is incorrect?

If it's incorrect, what is the difference between $P(D\mid M)$ and $P(D \cap M)$ in this question?

I am getting confused when to use conditional probability and intersection in such cases.

Comment: If three machines have $10\%$ defect ratio, and the others a $20\%$, then why are the other two termed 'defective'?

Comment: They are termed defective because they produce more defective items :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(D|M)$ is the probability that a perfect machine produces two faulty items out of five.

$P(D\cap M)$ is the probability that a perfect machine is picked *and* it's produced two faulty items out of five.

Those two probabilities are linked via Bayes' formula: $P(D\cap M)=P(D|M)P(M)$, and so the latter is $\frac{3}{5}$ (which is $P(M)$) of the former, i.e.

$P(D\cap M)=\frac{3}{5}{5\choose 2}(0.1)^2(0.9)^3$